# Icon not changing on onPressed

Tags: flutter, iconbutton

I am working on a larger project but do not know why this small part has kept me almost a whole day.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const AllTests());
}

class AllTests extends StatefulWidget {
  const AllTests({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AllTestsState createState() => _AllTestsState();
}

class _AllTestsState extends State<AllTests> {

  IconData play = Icons.play_circle_filled;
  onPressed(){
    if(play == Icons.play_circle_filled){
      play == Icons.pause_circle_filled_rounded;
    } else {
      play == Icons.play_circle_filled;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children:  [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  play,
                  size: 80,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ), 
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    print('hello');
                    onPressed();
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I just tried removing the **const** keyword before AllTests() but it is still now working.
I have also tried putting the function directly into the onPressed of IconButton.

the hello gets printed into the console, but the icon does not change. what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the `==` operator instead of the `=` operator. use this instead:

```
onPressed(){
if(play == Icons.play_circle_filled){
    play = Icons.pause_circle_filled_rounded;

} else {
    play = Icons.play_circle_filled;
}
}
```

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @AmiManye happy to help... if my answer solved your problem, I would be grateful if you tag it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `=` operator not the `==`.

```dart
onPressed() {
  if(play == Icons.play_circle_filled){
    play = Icons.pause_circle_filled_rounded;
  } else {
    play = Icons.play_circle_filled;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much